# Constraining locators in a locator pane to a specified data set

Tags: plotting, dynamic, gui-construction, locator

What is the best method to constrain multiple locator points to a set of data? A while back, I needed a program that could perform a linear fit for a specified range of data points. In an effort to create more work for myself, I decided to utilize `LocatorPane` to define end points for the fit range. The key to this program was constraining both locator points and making them snap-to points along the data set. I was able to cobble together code in *Mathematica* 10 that did just that (see example):

[image: my example]

Recently, I switched to a new version of *Mathematica* (11.0.1). Now, when I use this code, I get `Part` errors. Since my code is a bit ridiculous, I think the best option is a rewrite. What is the best method to constrain multiple locator points to a set of data?

I can attach my code if you'd like to take a look, but it's pretty messy.

Answer (score 10):

Use `Nearest[]`:

```
pts = {{1.0, 12.}, {1.9, 10.}, {2.6, 8.2}, {3.4, 6.9}, {5.0, 5.9}};
nf = Nearest[pts];

DynamicModule[{loc = pts[[{1, -1}]]}, 
              LocatorPane[Dynamic[loc, (loc = Flatten[nf[#], 1];) &], 
                          ListPlot[pts, Frame -> True]], SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

[image: locators constrained to a point set]

Comment: Excellent answer! I used Nearest in my old code, but I was completely unaware that you could use it on its own to generate a "Nearest" function. A few edits here and there and everything is working great. Thanks for the help!